# Returning a class with open zip/sql file

Tags: python

Sorry, I wasn't quite sure how to word the title.

I want somebody to be able to access the Connection class (say from a jupyter notebook) like so:

```py
import land

c = land.open("images")
c.list_images()
```

I keep getting a NoneType returned. I am not sure how to return an instantiation of the class properly so the sql and zip files can be accessed.

To be clear, my Connection class does have more methods implemented, including list_images(), I removed it from here for simplicity.

```py
# land.py
def open(name):
    c = Connection(name)
    return c

class Connection:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.db = sqlite3.connect(name+".db")
        self.zf = zipfile.ZipFile(name+".zip")
```

Comment: Just to clarify, in `land.py/open` returns `None`?

Comment: Did you define `list_images` in `Connection`?

Comment: @gnahum When I run c = land.open("images") in a jupyter to instantiate the object, I am getting a NoneType in return. I cannot run c.list_images()

Comment: @IvánC. Yes I did

Comment: in your jupyter notebook, can you do `c= Connection('images')`? Does this return null?

Answer (score 0):

i saw several problem with the code above :

1. You can't return value on `__init__`

   > Because **new**() and **init**() work together in constructing objects (**new**() to create it, and **init**() to customise it), no non-None value may be returned by **init**(); doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.
   >   [Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)
2. It's considered anti-pattern to explicitly return value on `__init__`. Let's take a look at example below.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.area = width * height
        return self.area
```

code above will causes "Explicit return in **init**" error

To dealing with this you need to remove return from `__init__` and move the logic into another instance method, so it became like this.

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self._area = width * height

    @property
    # moved the logic for returning area to a separate method
    def area(self):
        return self._area
```

In your scenario above it would became:

```
class Connection:
    def __init__(self, name):
        # you need to set name as property because this value is used in multiple places
        self._name = name

    @property
    def db(self):
        return sqlite3.connect(self._name+".db")

    @property
    def zip(self):
        return zipfile.ZipFile(self._name+".zip")
```